# how to store cache from UIWebViews which is in UICollectionView and display it in offline with swift?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3, uiwebview

I have 10 collectionView cells with web views controls. I need to store the cache from all the web views and use it when app moves in offline. 
I have done up to checking internet connection. Can anyone tell how to do?

Comment: maybe this link could help you http://robnapier.net/offline-uiwebview-nsurlprotocol

Comment: As a small note `UIWebView` is considered deprecated, you should be using `WKWebView`.

Comment: No i'm using UIWebView only @GuyKogus

Comment: Yes but you shouldn't be using `UIWebView`. The very first thing its class documentation says is to not use it.